# Executing an iMessage Extension app by clicking on a button in the main application

Tags: swift4, deep-linking, imessage-extension

Is it possible to launch my iMessage app extension from the main application( developed using Swift4), by clicking a button? I have already published the app in the store, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by using the same iTunes link for your app, with an added query parameter of `?app=messages`

Using Starbucks as an example, their App Store URL is

`https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/starbucks/id331177714`

But the URL to launch iMessage, and pull up your iMessage app would be

`https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/starbucks/id331177714?app=messages`

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I can tell, up as late as iOS 12.1

This is long-standing as a request - you can go only go in the one direction, from extension to App.

[There's a forum discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50375) from 2016 where the answer was that it's not possible. Another [2018 forum question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/324863#324863) got no response.

**From extension to app**, see the technique [described in this blog](http://www.rexfeng.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-open-phone-app-from-imessage-extension-and-pass-data/), using a URL:

```
guard let url: URL = URL(string: "AppName://?myParam=myValue") else { return }

self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: { (success: Bool) in

 })
```

Calling the above code will open the phone app.

You can access the URL params in your phone app’s App Delegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

return true
```

}